# Replace in SQL in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Still Having problems with replace. Using the following sql:

```
Dim UpDtFlag As String
    UpDtFlag = "UPDATE [Range Card Master Mailer] SET [Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemDate = Now(), [Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag = 'Y' " & _
    "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = '" & _
     Replace(Me!scanTxtBox, "'", "''") & "'))"
DoCmd.RunSQL UpDtFlag
```

The problem is in the Me!scanTxtBox.  Got help and and used it successfully in the following:

```
 Dim RCMSql As String
    RCMSql = "SELECT [Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].MaxOfDate_of_Transaction," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].FirstName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].LastName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Email_Address," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Address_Line_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_2," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Date_Sent," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].CouponValue," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemDate," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag " & _
    "FROM [Range Card Master Mailer] " & _
    "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = '" & _
     Replace(Me!scanTxtBox, "'", "''") & "'))"
     RCMRs.Open RCMSql
```

Tried to copy the replace into the problem query the problem query and obviously don't understand punctuation or something else. Also tried to use concatenation like BalanceStr = "'"&scanTxtBox&"'" and then use Balancestr in sql. Didn't work

Thanks

jpl

Comment: Replacing single quotes with two single quotes is a feeble attempt at preventing sql injection. Instead you should use parameterized queries. It is safe for your database and a LOT simpler for you to code it.

Comment: Sean, I don't understand.  Could you show an example of the parameter qurey the you describe, Please

Comment: @SeanLange - replacing a single quote with two quotes is for *escaping the single quote* so a string can be used in SQL.  Nothing to do with SQL injection, which is definitely something which needs to be considered, but is not something which always needs to be assumed will happen.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes that is correct but still...it is just the wrong way to go about it as it is a textbook example of sql injection.

Comment: This article will do a far better job of explaining this than a forum post will. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181734 You can also check out google for "vba parameterized query". You will get thousands of good examples.

Comment: It is not for sure "wrong" unless you know the context the OP is working in.

Comment: Ummm ok. They are taking the value of a textbox and directly executing it. There are pretty much no times that should be acceptable. It is so simple to parameterize queries once you know how to do it that not doing it is negligent.

Comment: I'm not trying to understate the potential risk of SQL injection, only stating an opinion that without understanding the actual risk given the expected use, it is over-reaching to claim that *any* SQL concatenation is unacceptable.

Comment: But in this case using parameterized sql solves the current issue AND makes it more secure. And even better, the OP will hopefully learn a less brittle technique for dealing with data. It is so simple to do that arguing that it doesn't matter in some situations is just silly.

Comment: I just want to know what to do to make the query run, like whats wrong with the Replace in UpDtFlag = "UPDATE [Range Card Master Mailer] SET [Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemDate = Now(), [Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag = 'Y' " & _
    "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = '" & _
     Replace(Me!scanTxtBox, "'", "''") & "'))" or am example of the parameter query.

Comment: @user3216034 did you look at the link I posted? It shows you how to do this pretty clearly.

Comment: Ahh just noticed you are using DoCmd. This should help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194182.aspx

Comment: Sean, I read the posts and tried the following but it gave me an error stating I need sql.  Here is what I tried: DoCmd.SetParameter "strTxtBox", Me.scanTxtBox.  Put in the sql and failure.  I am no expert at this so an example would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: `Debug.Print UpDtFlag` and check the output is what you expect, then try running that SQL directly in the actual Db and see what you get.  If you're trying to run an update in SQL server then `Now()` might need to be replaced with `getdate()` or something similar.

Comment: what type is the Master_ID ? number, string?

Comment: I don't know how to close this, but I got it running with the following"Dim UpDtFlag As String
        UpDtFlag = "UPDATE [Range Card Master Mailer] SET [Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemDate = Now(), [Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag = 'Y' " & _
        "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = '" & _
         Replace(Me!scanTxtBox, "'", "''") & "'))"
   'DoCmd.RunSQL UpDtFlag 'Reset after testing of printer

Answer (score 0):

I got it running with the following:

```
Dim UpDtFlag As String
UpDtFlag = "UPDATE [Range Card Master Mailer] SET [Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemDate = Now(), [Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag = 'Y' " & _
    "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID) = '" & _
     Replace(Me!scanTxtBox, "'", "''") & "'))"
DoCmd.RunSQL UpDtFlag 'Reset after testing of printer
```

Thanks

jpl